# returning listview clicked position to another activity

Tags: android, listview, methods, position

I'm having a very simple problem, which can be solved fairly simple but for some reason I cannot figure it out why is it not working.

I have a view composed of 6 Listviews and when the user clicks on a detail position I'm returning the position.
This position will be used to get the items from an entire row in a database.

When passing the position to another activity, The detail activity, the position I get is the one which I initialized, which is 0.

Here is my code.

1st Activity

The item click listener:

```
    detailsLi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aV, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*
                 * Intent openDetails = new Intent(
                 * "com.DCWebMakers.Vairon.APPOINTMENTDETAILS");
                 * startActivity(openDetails);
                 */
                positionView = detailsLi.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Dialog showPosition = new Dialog(MyAppointment.this);
                showPosition.setTitle("Position is:" + positionView);
            }
        });
```

the return position method:

```
public Integer getPosition() {
    return positionView;
}
```

2nd activity

Setting the row:

```
AppointmentInfo details = new AppointmentInfo(this);
        details.open();
        String name = details.getName(new MyAppointment().getPosition());
        details.close();
```

So, is the return position method not being used correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new MyAppointment().getPosition()
```

A new instance will return your default value. You should be passing the position:

In your list item click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.newactivity");   
intent.putExtra("list_position", arg2);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was getIntent().getExtras().getInt(   "position")

Answer (score 0):

`arg2` will give you the item position in the list..

to get the item use `aV.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString()`

Comment: But i don't want the items name at that position, because all of the items in the list view say detail. What I want was the position which was clicked example 0, 1, 2 3. That way when the new activity is started and opens the database to read an entire row of information it has which row to read